# Run and stop a monitoring command as sudo for s seconds every m minutes

Tags: cron, sudo, monitoring, timeout

I want to run `sudo airodump-ng -w myfile` every ten minutes or so, for m  minutes. It does not matter if the running time shifts (that it, if it runs m minutes later each time).

Notice that this is a monitoring program, which won't just output and exit. I suppose the solution for this one question is also valid for similar monitoring programs.

I was thinking about putting something like:

`*/10 * * * * airodump-ng mon0 -w myfile`

into `crontab`. There is no need to change the myfile name, airodump can correctly check whether myfile exists and create a myfile-02 and so on.

However, how should I stop it running after s secs? `pkill airodump` is the only thing I can think of. Is this the best for running it 1 minutes twice an hour?

`20,40 * * * * airodump-ng mon0 -w myfile`

`21,41 * * * * pkill airodump-ng`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `pkill`. Instead, run your app under the `timeout` command from the coreutils package:

```
*/10 * * * * timeout 5m airodump-ng mon0 -w myfile
```

(Where here `5m` means to run for 5 minutes.) Use `--signal` if you need something other than `TERM`.

Answer (score 0):

```
NEXT_WAIT_TIME=0
until command || [ $NEXT_WAIT_TIME -eq 4 ]; do
   sleep $(( NEXT_WAIT_TIME++ ))
done
```

or as one liner

```
NEXT_WAIT_TIME=0; until command || [ $NEXT_WAIT_TIME -q 4 ]; do sleep $(( NEXT_WAIT_TIME++ )); done
```

source:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12321815/3648121

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Added more information, how ever the answer @mattdm gave is way beter.